# How to add date in jboss logs, Logger is Java.util.logging.Logger

Tags: java, logging, jboss

I have been searching in net a lot but haven't manage to find the exact solution.
Currently the logs doesn't include date, it just include time
Ex:

```
12:31:24,733 INFO  [com ......]
```

I need to prefix date in the all the logs.

So I configured the formatter in `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/logging.property`
as

```
formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n
```

Then I could see, only starting jboss logs have date but then other JAVA logs doesn;t include date.

Example:

```
    30/07/2014 13:11:30,480 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.3.GA
    30/07/2014 13:11:30,642 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
    30/07/2014 13:11:30,699 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.3.Final "Arges" starting
    30/07/2014 13:11:31,468 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.6.GA
    30/07/2014 13:11:31,470 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
    30/07/2014 13:11:31,474 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.6.GA
    30/07/2014 13:11:31,482 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.8.SP1
    30/07/2014 13:11:31,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
    13:11:31,506 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 26) JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
    13:11:31,511 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
```

System: 
JAVA6, JBOSS7, RHEL6.4

Please let me know, how to I include date in all the jboss logs.

**UPDATE :**

Logging.property

```
# Additional logger names to configure (root logger is always configured)
loggers=org.jboss.as.config

# Dump system environment at boot by default
logger.org.jboss.as.config.level=DEBUG

# Root logger level
logger.level=${jboss.boot.server.log.level:INFO}
# Root logger handlers
logger.handlers=FILE,CONSOLE

# Console handler configuration
handler.CONSOLE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.ConsoleHandler
handler.CONSOLE.properties=autoFlush
handler.CONSOLE.level=${jboss.boot.server.log.console.level:INFO}
handler.CONSOLE.autoFlush=true
handler.CONSOLE.formatter=PATTERN
```

Above for CONSOLE handler

```
    # File handler configuration
    handler.FILE=org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.FileHandler
    handler.FILE.level=DEBUG
    handler.FILE.properties=autoFlush,fileName
    handler.FILE.autoFlush=true
    handler.FILE.fileName=${org.jboss.boot.log.file:boot.log}
    handler.FILE.formatter=PATTERN
```

Above for FILE handler

```
    # Formatter pattern configuration
    formatter.PATTERN=org.jboss.logmanager.formatters.PatternFormatter
    formatter.PATTERN.properties=pattern
    formatter.PATTERN.pattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] %s%E%n

Property
```

Answer (score 1):

The `java.util.Logger` system just like many other logging systems is hierarchical. You can define rules to nodes in the hierarchy which by default are inherited to child nodes. The hierarchy is often follows the java package hierarchy.

You should apply your format to the root or set it as the default. You should post your `logging.properties` file if you seek a more specific answer.

Read more about it in the javadoc of [java.util.Logger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: Thanks I have added the property file

Answer (score 1):

JBoss 7.1 
In Jboss management console, http://localhost:9990/console..., tab Profile -> Profile -> Core -> Logging, tab Handler, then tab Console and tab Periodic.

Formatter:

%d{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n.

and in my log file:   15.09.2016 13:51:13,577 INFO  [stdout] (http--192.168.0.182-7070-1) .....